# "Not defined as function or array" while compiling

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I have inherited some old code where each function is defined as an individual file. I am attempting to write a simple program to test this. I have written test.f a program that at its base calls the function in func.f and then reports the result.

Using `ifort -c func.f` I created the object file for func.f and then attempted to compile using `ifort test.f func.o -o test`. This gives me the error that func is not defined as a function or array. Any thoughts?

test.f is

```
      PROGRAM test
      REAL :: X,Y
      REAL :: FUNC
      X = 1.0
      Y = func(X)
      WRITE(6,*) X
      END
```

and func.f is

```
      FUNCTION func(X)
      func = X
      RETURN
      END
```

Comment: A couple of thoughts.  (1) Please include the exact error message you received.  (2) the `.f` extension is often interpreted to mean fixed-form source code.  The code needs to start in column 7.  Are the files formatted in this manner?  (3) If `func` is an external function, change the declaration to tell the compiler what it is, i.e., `real, external :: func`

Comment: Your program `test` does declare `func` to be a function (with result of type real), assuming this code is formatted correctly (see steve's comment), and no decent compiler will be fail to notice that unless you ask it to behave in a particular way. So please check that this source is exactly the code you pass to your compiler, check the options you give the compiler (not just on the command line), tell us what they are, and provide the exact error message.

Comment: Tidied the code up. It was a quick throw together to illustrate the issue I was experiencing. Unfortunately the system I’m building on is isolated from external networks so exact error messages will be difficult, I’ll hand scribble them down when I have access.

Comment: If this isn't code that you've confirmed that the compiler rejects, then I'm afraid there's not much sensible advice we can give you. ifort does issue errors about "not been declared as an array or a function" but that would not be expected in the code you show. (For example, if you also have `func` appear in an assignment statement or similar in the main program.)

Comment: Seems we can say something, sensible or not.

Answer (score 3):

A type declaration statement like

```
real func
```

declares that there exists an entity with name `func`. This may be either:

- a function with real result; or
- a variable of type real

In isolation, from just this declaration, it is not possible to determine which type of entity `func` is.

If `func` is not declared an array and there is no other use of `func` in the scope which is inconsistent with it being a function, then `func` is taken to be a function by any reference where it can be a function, such as

```
real func
print *, func(1)
end
```

In the absence of an array declaration for `func`, any use of `func` in the scope which is inconsistent with `func` a function will be an error. ifort will generally issue an error message in such case looking like

```
 error #6410: This name has not been declared as an array or a function.
```

What uses of `func` in a scope would be inconsistent with `func` a function? Just about anything that doesn't look like `f(...)` in an expression. For example:

- giving `func` some attribute a only variable may have
- using it as a variable in an assignment statement<sup>1</sup>
- providing explicit initialization
- using its name when a reference is required
- etc.

```
real :: func      ! Function or variable?
save func         ! Function can't be SAVEd
func = 1          ! Function name can't be on the left-hand side
print *, func     ! Function name can't be used in an expression
print *, func(1)  ! Oops, func isn't a function.

end
```

(All of these uses are consistent with being an array, we just haven't declared it as such.)

Some type declaration statements make it obvious the entity must be a variable:

```
real :: not_func = 1.
real, allocatable :: definitely_variable
real :: definitely_array(5)

end
```

That's all to say: if you intend to use `real func` to declare an external function `func` with implicit interface and real result, but you get a warning about "not an array or function" when you try to reference it then you've got something somewhere which means `func` isn't a function and you haven't said it's an array.

It could be quite boring to check for all cases where `func` could be misused, so let's make our life easier:

```
real, external :: func
```

Although without the `external` attribute specification the EXTERNAL attribute is applied if `func` is a function, there's certainly no harm it using it. Indeed, it's good: this way we've told the compiler that `func` really is a function. Which means that any use of `func` inconsistent with being a function is an error, instead of the function reference.

Try the previous example with `external` added.

You can also be precise about `func` being an external function using an interface block (good practice) or a procedure declaration statement.

---

<sup>1</sup> Although a function reference can be a variable, like in

```
func(1) = 12   ! func a function not an array
```

this is only the case when the function result is a pointer. A function with implicit interface cannot have a pointer result so this use is not consistent with `func` a function. We should also avoid confusion with the *statement function*

```
real :: func
func(i) = i+1
```

This *is* consistent with `func` a function, but it's not an external function defined elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Between all this info and a thorough review (at one point I’d initialised the function with a value, didn’t like that) I’ve managed to resolve the issue